# After Applied Array Their Location Changed

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I can not figure out the reason causing the mesh location to change after applied the array modifier. I have not had this problem before.

Applied LRS, it does not help. :D

Thanks for your time to take a look at this problem.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but make sure to set scale on objects before applying modifiers (ctrl+a > scale). Sometimes non-uniform scale causes issues.

Comment: Hi Chris, it is the same, I tried to apply the LRS. And Thanks. :D